# Google Sheets - Perform VLOOKUP on every row in column and return sum

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet where I have a column with some products in them. Each product has a price listed next to it. I have another sheet with sales, and a column has the product sold in the sale. I want a formula that produces the total price of every sale made, and products can be repeated.

Basically, if I have two products, A and B, with prices $1 and $2, then I have 3 sales, two of the sales use product A and one uses product B, the formula should return $4.

I tried using an ARRAYFORMULA with VLOOKUP and LOOKUP but no luck. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Here is an example sheet as requested. Feel free to edit it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1obHa6lbxJl_tJlQ811kjJralb7GCGjHtYBkOEPCzxAk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of  our sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 I added an example sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Sales!C2:C, Products!A:B, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]